# Yii2 - Advance Template with backend branches

Tags: yii, yii2

Please guide,

I once created a Yii2 app using a basic template.
Now, I am moving to advanced template.

Because i am facing a problem like this.

Let say, We have Headquarters and branch offices.
My question is the structured of app.

```
- backend
- frontend
```

I have 2 question,if I have structured like this:

```
- backend-master (abstract/interfaces class is came from this)
- backend-headquarters
- backend-branch-offices-1
- backend-branch-offices-2
- frontend
```

1. Is it good approach method ?
2. How to use a one layout web to all backend

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. All you need is actually a sub module. not a separate backend module like this.
2. You may configure each sub-module to use the view file from any sub-module inside backend module in each of your sub-module configuration.

backend/module/headquaters/module/config/main.php (i assume)

```
'components' => [
    ... other components
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => [
                 // you may specify any directory as your view directory from here
                '@backend/views' => '@backend/views',
                '@frontend/adminlte/views' => '@frontend/themes/adminlte/views',
            ],
        ],
    ],
     ... other components
```